# Windows placement problem in Join Displays mode when displays stacked vertically - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors

I have set Join Displays with my primary display (1366x768) at the bottom and the secondary (1680x1050) at the top and I get some vertical placement issues with some windows. The two cases that I have encountered so far:

1. The System Settings window. When I run/open System Settings its title bar always appears off the primary/bottom screen, it goes to the secondary/top one.
2. Some third-party app. It has the main window and dozens of other windows that you pop up as needed. One of those always pops up on the secondary display even though the main program window runs on the primary display.

I tried to drag the windows to the desired position and close them there. I also tried CompizConfig Settings Manager with the "Place Windows" thing selected. And I also gave it a restart just in case.

My wild guess is that the difference in vertical resolution has something to do with it because when I choose to put displays side-by-side (i.e. to be extended horizontally) suddenly all the windows appear where I expect them to. No problems at all.

Comment: You tried Compiz Config Settings manager? Do you run the Unity desktop? Or perhaps mate or xfce with Compiz? The current standard desktop of Ubuntu does not run on Unity.

Comment: @vanadium As I said "I also tried CompizConfig Settings Manager with the "Place Windows" thing selected". Is there anything else I can do with this CompizConfig Manager? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 as is. If it comes with the Unity desktop and runs it by default then I do run it if not then I don't. The same about mate and xfce.

Comment: So then you are running the standard version with the Gnome desktop. Forget about Compiz in that case, because Compiz cannot be used with the Gnome desktop.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you. I installed it and tried to enable that "Place Windows" feature only because it was recommended in some answer here askubuntu.com. Just to make clear the problem I described in my question started before I tried to mess with the CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Comment: Perhaps try the setting "Center new window" in Gnome Tweaks. That will replace the "smart" placing algorithm by opening new windows in the center of the screen, which you then will need to move, though. There is nothing you can do more fundamentally about the issue, I am afraid, except placing the secondary monitor on the right instead of on top.

Comment: @vanadium I tried the "Center new windows" and I didn't notice the difference. The windows still pop up in the wrong places, with no logic to it. I should probably try some other distribution. Thank you.